# Load offline map in qt qml using .osm or .osm.pbf

Tags: qt, qml, maps, offline

1. We want to implement offline map in our qt project using SD card or local storage. I have downloaded both .osm and .osm.pbf files. Now we need method/process to load a offline map in qt using .osm or .osm.pbf.
2. Is there a way to display offline maps in QtLocation without generating tiles? Like reading directly from a osm file. If it is not possible in QtLocation, is there any other modules available that I can use in QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to load offline tiles. This property works from QtLocation 5.8 onward.

```
Map {
      activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[1]
      zoomLevel: 5
      plugin: Plugin {
         name: 'osm';
         PluginParameter {
            name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
            value: '/path/to/map/tiles'

           }
       }
}
```

You can also take a look at [QtLocation Offline](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qtlocation-using-offline-map-tiles-openstreetmap-plugin)